# spectral projection endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering about a statement in linear algebra.

If we have the endomorphism $u$ which is in its canonical basis represented by
  \begin{pmatrix}
   5 & 1 & 3 \\
   4 & 3 & 4 \\
   -1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

I have computed according to u his spectral decomposition and we have $\pi_2=\frac{1}{2}(u-3ID)(u-4Id)$
$\pi_3=-(u-2ID)(u-4Id)$
$\pi_4=\frac{1}{2}(u-2Id)(u-3Id)$

And then I would like to express $u^n$. In my book they say that from $Id_{\mathbb{R^3}}=\pi_2+\pi_3+\pi_4$ we deduce $u^n=2^n\pi_2+3^n\pi_3+4^n\pi_4$

Ho did they manage to express $u^n$ this way ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The eigen value of $u$ are 2,3 and 4 there is $P$ such that $u=Pdiag(2,3,4)P^{-1}$

So $u^n=Pdiag(2^n,3^n,4^n)P^{-1}$

Let $E_{i,j} = (e_{i,j})$ with $e_{i,j} = 0$ if $i  \neq j $ and $e_{i,i} = 1$

So $u^n=2^nPE_{1,1}P^{-1}+3^nPE_{2,2}P^{-1}+4^nPE_{3,3}P^{-1}$

and $\pi_i=PE_{i-1,i-1}P^{-1}$

Therefore, $u^n=2^n\pi_2+3^n\pi_3+4^n\pi_4$